# C++: Discerning polymorphic events in event system

Tags: c++, event-handling, queue, polymorphism, rtti

I'm currently trying to write an event system in C++. The problem is quite specific so sorry for the long read...

---

## What works?

The `Events` look like this:

```cpp
class IEvent { //interface stuff };

class EventA : public IEvent { // A implementation };

class EventB : public IEvent { // B implementation };
```

Now all objects that shall receive and process events are based on an `EventHandler` interface:

```cpp
class IEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual void eventCallback(IEvent*) = 0;
};

// Example implementation
class HandlerImplementation : public IEventHandler
{
public:
    // Overloads for several events (different for each implementation of the handler interface)
    virtual void eventCallback(EventA*) { cout << "This is an A event." << endl; }
    virtual void eventCallback(EventB*) { cout << "This is a B event." << endl; }
    // "Fallback"
    virtual void eventCallback(IEvent*) override { cout << "Some other event..." << endl; }
};
```

This works as expected. Each class built on my `EventHandler` interface will call the appropriate callback function for each `Event` type (or the default function):

```cpp
int main()
{
    class EventC : public IEvent {};
    EventA a;
    EventB b;
    EventC c;

    HandlerImplementation handler;
    handler.eventCallback(&a); // This is an A event.
    handler.eventCallback(&b); // This is a B event.
    handler.eventCallback(&c); // Some other event...
}
```

---

## What does not work?

Events should not always be handled whenever they occur. Handlers might want to buffer them, so processing can be scheduled.

I tried to extend the `EventHandler` interface like so:

```cpp
class IEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual void eventCallback(IEvent*) = 0;
private:
    std::priority_queue<IEvent*> event_queue;
};
```

However the `IEvent` pointers, that are stored in this queue, will of course only trigger the "default" callback and never one of the overloads.

Is there any way of "remembering" which `Event` types have been up-casted to `IEvent*` or do you know of any patterns to avoid this situation altogether?

Comment: Can you show more documentation of what you believe is happening? I'm confident that C++ does not work the way you describe it working. Invoking `eventCallback` via an `IEventHandler` will ***always*** dispatch to the "some other" override, and not to the "appropriate" one, as you seem to be believe. Using a priority queue, or any other container has absolutely nothing to do with anything, makes no difference whatsoever, and does not change this behavior. How a pointer to a virtual base class behaves does not change if it's stored in a container. There's nothing to "remember".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I hope the added code snipped helps.

Comment: That's because you are invoking `handler`'s method ***directly with a pointer to the derived class instead of the base class***, and you're invoking the implementation class method's ***directly*** instead of via the interface base clsas. Now, add `IEvent &abase=a;` to your `main` followed by `handler.eventCallback(&abase);` and see what happens. This has nothing to do with a priority queue. C++ simply does not work this way. You cannot "remember" anything once you only have a pointer to a base class, the only option is a pile of ugly code that uses `dynamic_cast`, and hopes for the best.

Comment: Or, add `IEventHandler &ie=handler;`, instead, and attempt to invoke `ie.eventCallback(...)`. Same results.

Comment: You can "remembering" which Event types have been up-casted to `IEvent*` by having a separate event queue for each type.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am aware that it is the *type* of the pointer decides which callback function will be invoked. I do not know where my question would have implied anything else.

Comment: @Galik Good idea but I'm afraid this would make things a little complicated since the entire point of having one `priority_queue` is to only work on the most important events at a time.

Comment: Correct, except that the "type of the pointer", when invoking `IEventHandler::eventCallback`, is always `IEvent *`. To do what you're trying to do requires a fundamental redesign of all the shown classes. Yes, it is possible to implement something that will end up invoking the appropriate method, using the original pointer type. But this needs to be done in a completely different manner, not what's shown here. Run a Google search for "double dispatch" for more information.

Comment: Given your naming scheme, it looks like you are trying to translate a Java-based or C#-based solution to C++. That's not always a good idea. Java and C# have built-in introspection while C++ does not.

Comment: @DavidHammen I actually have no (significant) experience in both Java and C# :D